# I can't add a GitHub project in Careers 2.0 because I'm "just" an author

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, github

I am involved in a project on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) that is not mine. Nevertheless, my team added me to the project as author.

On [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Careers) 2.0, I am only able to add project I created (so within my "namespace"), or project of other I forked.

I don't know how far you track users and their project, but I think it could be fair to be able to link on a team project where the user is the author but not the owner.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Or what happens when you try to do this?

Comment: No it is just not in the list of "addable" project.

Comment: Can you send me a link to the project? We do support Github organizations.

Comment: @Matt the project is here. https://github.com/prologin/prolojail But I'm not sure the account is an "organisation" account. Pretty much like StackExchange scripts of `@Rebecca` https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts . Multiple people are able to commit and push on the project, but `@Rebecca` owns the repository.

Comment: Thanks. The Github API (v2) is surprisingly roundabout for this sort of thing. We’ll investigate v3…

Comment: It should even be possible to add projects where you don’t have any commit rights at all – you might have made substantial contributions anyway. Unfortunately, the manual adding mode does not [help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106775) either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is that we haven't figured out a good way to do this with the GitHub API. It's a common request, and we'll announce if/when we figure it out.

**Update:** You can now add projects from your organization if you are a public member (see [setting your organization membership to public](https://help.github.com/articles/publicizing-or-concealing-organization-membership/)  - it's private by default). You need to have made at least one commit to the repo for the project to be visible on your profile.

Comment: can't one rely (at least in part) on the goodwill of people that will edit their resumé and let them manually add the appropriate repositories?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by making sure I was a **public** member of the organization. By default membership is private.