# Manual open source import rejects GitHub projects, even foreign ones

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, github

The "Add Other Open Source Project" link rejects any GitHub link referring to the GitHub import. Unfortunately, many GitHub projects to which you might have contributed could not be added from the GitHub import (see [I can't add a GitHub project in Careers 2.0 because I'm "just" an author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101899)).

Answer (score 1):

Housecleaning: at some point we added the ability to import projects from organizations you belong to (even if you don't own them).