# Careers should allow me to add external (authored but not owned) GitHub projects under "other"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, github

On Careers, when you try to add open source GitHub entries, it shows you repos which you own or are owned by an organization which you collaborate on.

[However, one cannot add user owned GitHub projects which one is a collaborator on, or GitHub projects that one has pull-requested to many times.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101899/i-cant-add-a-github-project-in-careers-2-0-because-im-just-an-author)

This would be fine with me; that just means that there isn't any fancy fetching of the project details via the API.

However, it isn't possible to add *any* GitHub projects via the "other" button; it throws the error "Please use our GitHub page (/import/github/88888) to add Github projects.".

Which means that I can *only* link to a small subset of the projects available on GitHub, even though I can link to almost anything else on the Internet via the other option.

Could the restriction on GitHub links in the "other" form be removed? It could instead be replaced with a non-blocking "warning" sort of thing.

Alternatively, keep a textbox at the bottom of the GitHub repo list where I can enter my own repo.

Comment: Please fix this. I have released as sole contributor a bunch of packages under various organizations, yet they don't show up in the Careers GitHub list. Instead, I see a ton of packages for which I've only made one commit long time ago.

Answer (score 5):

We've now added this.

On your profile, under the "Open Source" section, go to add or update GitHub and you'll see a new section at the end of your repository list:

[image: Manually add a repository]

Enter the URL of the repo and click "add". Then we'll pull up the repo details and you can add it to your profile.

But wait! What's to stop you just going in and adding somebody else's GitHub repo to your profile?

Well, of course you wouldn't do that, because you're an honest person, and you don't tell lies.

And we check as well. When you add a repository to your profile, it won't actually appear on the version employers see until we've verified it. We check to see if you've actually made commits to the repo before others can see it.

You'll see a note about this when editing your profile - there will be a notification under the project if it's still awaiting verification, or if we checked it and couldn't see any commits you made.

Comment: I have made at least 10 commits after submitting it to stackoverflow. But I still see the message "We couldn't find any commits you've made to this project.".  why so?