# "Hidden" We couldn't find any commits you've made to this project. Careers.SO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

Recently I linked my Careers profile with Github and I added a project I recently contributed to but am amazed to see a notice which says

> **Hidden** We couldn't find any commits you've made to this project.

But if you see, I do have a [commit](https://github.com/PeeHaa/OpCacheGUI/commits?author=mr-alien) to this project so why is Careers.SO unable to grab that and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Careers profile actually lists your fork, https://github.com/mr-alien/OpCacheGUI

That fork received its last commit on July 26th https://github.com/mr-alien/OpCacheGUI/commits/master

But your commit appears in the main repository in October https://github.com/PeeHaa/OpCacheGUI/commits?author=mr-alien

So your fork is out of date - it doesn't have your own commit in it!

You can either:

- re-fork the main repository
- list the main repository manually (you can add GitHub URLs manually now - as of [only a few days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214438/careers-should-allow-me-to-add-external-authored-but-not-owned-github-projects/244121#244121))

Then we'll be able to see your commit, and the project will be displayed on your profile.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will check asap

Comment: How does SE know if its a commit by me. I use my personal address at SE and my work email on Github. Could this be a problem?

Comment: @ZiyanJunaideen If you're using the same GitHub account it will be picked up.