# careers, github project is hidden

Tags: support, jobs

For some reason http://careers.stackoverflow.com says:

Hidden We couldn't find any commits you've made to this project.

For https://github.com/Karaage-Cluster/karaage/commits/master

This is just a bit weird, because I have made a lot of commits to this project, and github is correctly seeing them as my commits.

Possibly problem is the commits were made with my old email address. My research seems to suggest this shouldn't matter though, as long as github can associate it to my user.

Comment: Not sure why this was put on hold. This seems to be the site other people are asking similar questions. Where should I be asking for help?

Comment: In fact the link you showed has "Stack Overflow Careers" site as on topic here.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious the error I quoted comes from Stack Overflow Careers (I think I made that clear), and this is the only place I can find to get support for Stack Overflow Careers. It is pretty pathetic if stackexchange is not interested in receiving bug reports for their own software and marks such reports as off-topic instead.

Comment: Here is an example of a similar question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244434/hidden-we-couldnt-find-any-commits-youve-made-to-this-project-careers-so?rq=1 - unfortunately the resolution does not apply here.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275771/where-do-i-get-support-for-stack-overflow-careers