# Where do I get support for Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: support, jobs, site-recommendation

According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Stack Overflow Careers should be on topic here. However I had a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274539/careers-github-project-is-hidden) about a possible bug closed with the reason "This question pertains only to a specific site in the Stack Exchange Network". I tried asking about this in the comments but got no responses. So if this is the wrong place for this type of question, where is the correct place to ask for support? Or is careers.stackoverflow.com a website with no support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page should be updated indeed.

Since Careers is deprecated and now specific to Stack Overflow (hence the name Stack Overflow Jobs), all questions on that [should go](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274213/245360) on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Is anybody going to update that page?

Comment: I hope so. I guess it is on the radar of the team already. If not, I will ping them some time

Comment: @PenguinBrian I updated the page to be clearer. Dealing with your question on SO now.