# careers.stackoverflow.com should allow multiple bitbucket profiles

Tags: feature-request, jobs, github

It's not uncommon to have multiple profiles on bitbucket and/or belong to multiple teams. For example to be part of the company team as well as having a separate blog profile (for demo projects) and a personal profile.

`careers.stackoverflow.com` should allow to either import multiple profiles from bitbucket *or* should also add all projects of all teams the person is part of. Actually I think both should be added.

This problem is made worse by bitbucket's decision to disallow team logins. So I cannot even switch to a team for granting careers.stackoverflow.com access. I'm limited to a profile without any interesting projects.

Comment: Is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214438/152859) the same request?

Comment: More like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101899/i-cant-add-a-github-project-in-careers-2-0-because-im-just-an-author) (which was linked to in the one, you mentioned). Since it's status-completed it might work for github (can't test it for GH). but it definitely is not fixed for bitbucket.

Comment: @Max but OP here claims it's still not working for bitbucket so it this really completed?

Comment: @ShadowWizard maybe not, will check.

Comment: @Max in such case we can edit this post to ask only for Bitbucket multiple profiles support.

Comment: Multiple profiles from Bitbucket are already supported. I just tested this - if I log into a second Bitbucket account (directly via the Bitbucket website), coming back to Edit Profile and clicking "add bitbucket" allows me to import the repos from it too.

Comment: But careers does not support projects of the teams you belong to - and you cannot directly login to teams on bitbucket.