# Careers is not showing repository that I contributed as collaborator

Tags: support, jobs, github

I went through this question posted previously here: [I can't add a GitHub project in Careers 2.0 because I'm "just" an author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101899/)

I am collaborator for [this](https://github.com/akumar34/DivvyBikes_Visualization) repository. Will there be an option to make the repositories I contributed as public? I did this for organizations but couldn't do it for repositories I contributed to (these are not categorized in to an organization). So I cannot see the repositories I contributed.